# Which country’s hams have the longest call signs?

Tags: callsign

Not including special event callsigns, which group (country/class/etc) of hams have and use the longest callsigns?

I know that theoretically the longest would be a (3x4) or 8 character callsign but are these in use? I’m interested in which countries in actual practice issue incredibly long callsigns to individuals.

Comment: I am unaware of any "incredibly long" (not sure how you define) callsigns other than special events.  Australia regularly issues a foundation license of the form VK#ABCD which is a rare (unique?) four-letter suffix. Swaziland is also (rather) unique in that its common national prefix is three characters (3DA) then a numeral and a suffix.

Comment: Are you writing some logging software? I can't think of any other reason why someone would want to know this.

Comment: Just curious. Some American hams have incredibly short 4 letter 1x2 callsigns but I was curious about the other extreme, which country’s hams had the unfortunate pleasure of having the longest regular callsigns.

Answer (score 4):

A long call sign that was recently pointed out on this site is a special club call sign in Belgium. As discussed [here](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/10231/long-callsigns-in-wsjt-x), it is too long to be encoded in FT-8 and is in the form OT70xxx.

Answer (score 3):

Several nations have special event stations with call signs longer than normal. I know of one nation which issues 3-character prefixes (Eswatini), but those are all 3x2 call signs (3DAnxx). Australia until recently issued 2x4 calls (VKnFxxx) but stopped a little while ago. The USA once issued multiple number calls for special events IE W100AW. The longest I know of would have to be the STAYHOME call signs IE [OH2STAYHOME](https://www.qrz.com/db/OH2STAYHOME) which would be a 2x8 call sign, but are special events. Portable call signs such as VK6Fxxx/3DA0 could be a long call sign, but isn't issued per se. If that counts, a state QSO party call such as AI7OW/KITSAP would also qualify.

UPDATE: Guinea issues 3x1 call signs along with 2x1 and 2x2, 3XY*n*?